# How we can add Space among the resulted Value/String we are getting from RDLC Expression

Tags: rdlc

How we can add Space among the resulted Value/String we are getting from RDLC Expression.
In the below mentioned expression we want to add space after "Start Date". But HTML style and Space () are not applying together when Placeholder is Interpreted with HTML Tags in RDLC Reports

```
="Start Date:"  &space(10) &  "<span style='color:red'>" & Parameters!DateFrom.Value & "</span>"


="Start Date:"  & "<span style='color:red; margin-left:10px;'>" & Parameters!DateFrom.Value & "</span>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace with a non-breaking space character so that `&space(10) &` gets replaced with `& Replace(Space(10), " ", "&nbsp;") &`